# Overwriting the values in jTable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-6.9

Why does the value in my jTable overwrites the first value which are
selected from the jcombobox? can somebody help me out with this code:

```
private void jButton15ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;
    try {
        // TODO add your handling code here
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
    try {
        con= DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:food");
        stmt= con.createStatement();
        int row = 0;

        String st= JcbSub.getSelectedItem().toString();
        jTable3.setValueAt(st, row, 0);    

            row ++;

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please clarify: what is your code specifically not doing that you are expecting it to do? What is it currently doing that you don't expect it to be doing? What is the code above supposed to represent? Where is there anything in the code above that refers to any JComboBox? How is this JComboBox related to the problem? Why do you have default comments in the code and no comments that might help us understand the code?

Comment: variable name of jComboBox here is JcbSub.
i want to increment the row on every selection.

Comment: i dont want to overwrite the first row on evry selction from the jcbSub into jTable

Comment: dear try to be a little cool and try to understand what a person wants to convey.
i have got the answer and it right beneath you.

Comment: think before you unlike the question.

Comment: dont take it to the heart just advising you... :-)
no offence

Comment: No offense taken. Try to ask a question with the view that we can't understand that which is not spoken or see code not shown. The more informative the question the better the answer.

Comment: well i am new at java and stack overflow as well so kindly compensate me with this.
still sorry for the word if you have felt them harsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you do increment the row number at the end you've declared it as a ***local variable*** *which loses its value and gets initialized to 0* at every method call. Hence your first row gets overwritten everytime.

```
int row = 0; // move this out to a member variable

String st= JcbSub.getSelectedItem().toString();
jTable3.setValueAt(st, row, 0);    

row ++; // this increment currently has no effect on next method call
```

You're also opening a new database connection every time and not closing it by calling `con.close()`. In fact, since you're not executing any queries via your `Statement` object stmt there's no need for all the JDBC code inside the method.

Comment: so how can i get rid of this problem?

Comment: i want to incrment the row in the jTable on every selection

Comment: Make it a member variable i.e. declared within the class body outside the method.

Comment: you mean to say i should declare the "int row = 0" globally?

Comment: Yes, as an instance variable instead of a method local variable.

Answer (score 1):

`JTable#setValue` will only change an existing rows value.

Your should use the `TableModel` to add new rows. If your using a `DefaultTableModel` you could use the [`addRow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) method

Comment: can you please edit the code for me because i am new at java.

Comment: Then I suggest a read through [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) is your next priority

Answer (score 0):

your code is incomplete, i supose because u didnt use anything of the created statement and the row isnt inside any loop to travel inside any data set.

the jtable.setValueAt  method needs the value , the index of col, and the index of the row,

setValueAt(Object o, int col, int row)

you are just setting the first row when put the zero at the last parameter 
 jTable3.setValueAt(st, row, 0);